# I am getting an Index error as list out of range. I have to scan through many lines

Tags: python, indexing, nltk

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize


file = open("sms.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    #print line
    a=word_tokenize(line)
    if a[5] == 'SBI' and a[6]== 'Debit':
        print a[13]
```

Could any one please help me in rectifying the error. The programme runs for a few lines then stops and gives an index out of range error. I understand the error but I dont know how to fix it. I want to basically remove the lines which have are not readable.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace form the error you are getting?

Comment: Do you mean the line in which I'm getting error? but there are many such lines.

Comment: Generally it means that you are providing an index for which a list element does not exist. Try to print every line.

Comment: Maybe you can check length of a. Like if len(a) >= 14 etc?

Comment: You can check the whole line to see what the contents of the list `a` actually are. Then you can see if you need to correct your logic. `if a[5] == 'SBI' and a[6]== 'Debit':
        print a`

Comment: The traceback is the text of the error you are getting. It includes the line with the text "IndexError..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `list length` check would solve the problem.

```
if len(a) >= 14 and a[5] == 'SBI' and a[6]== 'Debit':
    print a[13]
```

Comment: It worked the second time I ran it. Strange. Thank you

Comment: @KapilVaswani if this answer helped you, please consider  accepting this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. Also, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204038/extract-a-column-from-text-file/32204326#32204326 as it's directly related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also track the inappropriate line without affecting the flow/without error

```
    file = open("sms.txt", "r")
    for line_no,line in enumerate(file):
        a=word_tokenize(line)
        try:
            if a[5] == 'SBI' and a[6]== 'Debit':
                print a[13]
        except IndexError:
            print str(line_no)+" line doesn't have expected data"
            continue
```

Comment: You can catch the except print statement in to a file if required